# MySQL - JOIN multiple rows to single row multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to `join` multiple rows of information for single row, but it seems to multiply every time there is more rows in one of the joins.

My tables structure is as follows:

```
news
id  |  title  |  public
------------------------
1   |  Test   |  0


news_groups_map
id  |  news_id  |  members_group_id
------------------------------------
1   |  1        |  5
2   |  2        |  6


members_groups_map
id  |  member_id  |  group_id
------------------------------
1   |  750        |  5
2   |  750        |  6
```

The query I've got so far is:

```
SELECT 
n.title, 
n.public, 

CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(ngm.members_group_id) AS CHAR(1000)) AS news_groups,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(member_groups.group_id) AS CHAR(1000)) AS user_groups

FROM news n

LEFT JOIN news_groups_map ngm ON n.id = ngm.news_id

JOIN (
    SELECT group_id
    FROM members_groups_map
    WHERE member_id = 750
) member_groups

WHERE n.public = 0
GROUP BY n.id
```

However, the result is as follows:

```
title  |  public  |  news_groups  |  user_groups
-------------------------------------------------
Test   |  0       |  5,6,5,6      |  6,6,5,5
```

As you can see, the `news_group` and `user_groups` are duplicating, so if a news article is in 3 groups, the `user_groups` will be multiplied as well and show something like `5,6,6,6,5,5`.

How can I group those groups, so that they are only displayed once?

The ultimate goal here is to compare `news_groups` and `user_groups`. So if at least one group matches (meaning user has enough permissions), then there should be a boolean with `true` returned, and `false` otherwise. I don't know how to do that either, however, I thought I should sort out the grouping first, as once the number of groups gets bigger there is going to be unnecessary lots of same data selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to use `distinct`:

```
SELECT n.title, n.public, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ngm.members_group_id) AS news_groups,     
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mg.group_id) AS user_groups
FROM news n LEFT JOIN
     news_groups_map ngm
     ON n.id = ngm.news_id CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT group_id
      FROM members_groups_map
      WHERE member_id = 750
     ) mg
WHERE n.public = 0
GROUP BY n.id;
```

This query doesn't actually make sense.  First, the subquery is not needed:

```
SELECT n.title, n.public, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ngm.members_group_id) AS news_groups,     
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCTD mg.group_id) AS user_groups
FROM news n LEFT JOIN
     news_groups_map ngm
     ON n.id = ngm.news_id CROSS JOIN
     members_groups_map mg
     ON member_id = 750
WHERE n.public = 0
GROUP BY n.id;
```

Second, the `CROSS JOIN` (or equivalently, `JOIN` without an `ON` clause) doesn't make sense.  Normally, I would expect a join condition to one of the other tables.

Comment: Thanks, `DISTINCT` didn't even come to my head for some reason. You make a good point, I could just get the `user_groups` ready before the query instead of the `member_id`. In that case, how could I use that to cross-check with `news_groups`? For single value I could use `IN`, but how can I check multiple values with functionality of `or` (so either value match)?

Answer (score 1):

Use DISTINCT in the GROUP_CONCAT

```
...
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ngm.members_group_id) AS CHAR(1000)) AS news_groups,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT member_groups.group_id) AS CHAR(1000)) AS user_groups
...
```